How do I get a list or array data type out of PyQt5 QSQLQuery using PostgreSQL database?
I have a basic database setup using postgresql. One of the columns has a real[] data type set, but no matter what I do the resulting value from a qsqlquery returns a string type instead of an array or a list. Other datatypes like bool and bytea work fine. Does that mean that PyQt doesn't support the return of a list data type from the query?
Tried running a basic select qsqlquery statement on the database to get rows of values. The query returns the values correctly but not in the right data type. I was expecting the values to be returned as a python list type but the values are strings instead. I also tried an unnest statement to check that the data in the column is actually an array of real numbers, it is, the qsqlquery returns a float data type for every value.

Qt does not currently support arrays in any of its database backends. There's only boolean, integer, real, text, date/time, bytes and null. The exact mapping of data-types for each database is given here: Data Types for Qt-supported Database Systems.
